# What is the problem with transposed matrix?

Tags: c++

I have tried to make matrix transpose function, it works perfect when i use square matrix, but when I try to use matrix size like 2x3 or 5x7 it outputs not correct transposed matrix.
I used function to enter and output arrays, in entering I had returned new array, that contains entered values. Also I used *transpose* function, that create new array with the same size as a matrix that provided to function. Actually I don't understand why this code works with square matrix and doesn't work with random size matrix.
Code that i used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>

float *enterArr (int m, int n, char name);
void showArr(float *M, int m, int n, char name);
float *transp(float *M, int m, int n);

int main() {
    float *A, *B, *P, *Q;
    int ma, na, mb, nb;
    printf("Enter size of %c matrix : ", 'A');
    scanf("%i %i", &ma, &na);
    printf("Enter size of %c matrix : ", 'B');
    scanf("%i %i", &mb, &nb);
    if (ma == 0 or na == 0 or mb == 0 or nb == 0)
        puts("You have entered invalid values");
    else
    {
        A = enterArr(ma, na, 'A');
        B = enterArr(mb, nb, 'B');
    
        showArr(A, ma, na, 'A');
        showArr(B, mb, nb, 'B');
    
        P = transp(A, ma, na);
        Q = transp(B, mb, nb);
    
        puts("Transposed matrix: ");
        showArr(P, na, ma, 'P');
        showArr(Q, nb, mb, 'Q');    
    }
    
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    return (0);
}

float *transp (float *M, int m, int n) {
    int i, j, mm;
    float *tr;
    mm = m*n;
    tr = new float[mm];
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) 
            tr[i*n+j] = M[i+j*n];
    return tr;
}

void showArr(float *M, int m, int n, char name) {
    int i, j;
    printf("Maxtrix %c: \n", name);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%9.4f", M[i*n+j]);  
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

float *enterArr (int m, int n, char name) {
    int i, j, mm;
    float *M;
    mm=m*n;
    M = new float [mm];
    printf("Enter elements of %c matrix\n", name);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            scanf("%f", &M[i*n+j]); 
        }
    }
    return M;
}
```

Comment: `new float [mm]` means this definitely isn't C. It's C++ but you're using C headers and I/O for some reason.

Comment: In c++ is it advised to use `std::vector` instead of raw c arrays.

Comment: I imagine `tr[i*n+j] = M[i+j*n]` should be `tr[i*n+j] = M[i+j*m]`

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to allocate a new array that has the opposite dimensions of the input matrix

```
float *transp(float *M, int m, int n) {
    int i, j;
    float *tr = new float[n*m];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
              tr[i*m+j] = M[j*n+i];
         }
    }
    return tr;
}
```